# How to find out what code in a C# .NET assembly is not being called

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# .NET assembly, in visual studio 2008. If required I could upgrade it to VS 2010.

How can I find which code in the assembly is not called? Ideally if something could analyse the whole solution in one go. It is too much for me to analyse it all myself manually.

The assembly is shared between a client and server project so I need to understand which code is used where.

Comment: I'm going to need a little more to go on. One option would be to temporarily litter the code with MessageBox's to see what code is executing..

Comment: MessageBox? Yikes. Log statements would be better (not that I think this is a good way to do it).

Comment: There are two kinds, classes and methods that actually get referenced in your code but just never actually get used because the logic doesn't need them.  And just plain litter, like an event handler method that never is subscribed or a class that somebody factored out but forgot to delete.  Litter requires a very different tool.

Comment: Lynn, sorry, I'm not buying into your suggestion there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hans, good thoughts. It is a bit like this. One VS 2008 solution = server project, and another VS 2008 solution = client project. A couple of visual studio projects are shared between them. So some classes on those shared projects have methods that are called from the server project, and some methods that are called from the client project. It is pretty ugly actually, but it is legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting resharper. That does that for you. You can get a free trial version from their website. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2010 you can use [code coverage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504821.aspx) together with unit tests for that - so if you can refactor your client code into actual unit tests you can use that.

To quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx):

> To determine what proportion of your
>   project's code is actually being
>   tested using unit tests, you can use
>   the code coverage feature of Visual
>   Studio Application Lifecycle
>   Management. To do this, first edit the
>   run configuration to indicate the
>   assembly that contains the code whose
>   coverage you want to measure. Then run
>   tests on that code. Detailed code
>   coverage statistics appear in a
>   window, and you can also see,
>   line-by-line, which code has been
>   tested.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a method of detecting code used by Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Providing you don't mind buying something to do it, ReSharper will go off and find unused code for you.

Answer (score 1):

FxCOP is a free tool from Microsoft that includes dead code detection.

For best resulsts, don't mark classes/methods public unless they really need to be public. It assumes that any public method is used by external assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx) in Visual Studio, [help here](http://devonenote.com/2010/03/find-dead-code/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [safe delete](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Safe_Delete) function of ReSharper, keeping in mind it will say it's safe to delete code which is only used via reflection (such as Fluent automapping conventions).

Couldn't hurt to download a 30 day trial to see if it does what you need anyhow.

Comment: Safe delete has been working for me so far. A true call tree would be better but I don't have any way to get that in a timely fashion.